# Are there any official counters which keep a track on the number of downloads of a particular Ubuntu version across different derivatives?

Tags: community

Are there any official counters which keep a track on the number of downloads of a particular Ubuntu version across different derivatives? If there are no official counters, is there any source which would help me make a reliable estimate about the number of downloads?

I need this information for my project, specifically for Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Statistics are outside the scope of the site and are classified as off-topic.

Comment: You may want to ask this on the [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/) or [Ubuntu Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/) its off topic here but not on those sites.

Comment: I've reopened this [because](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8099/lets-identify-if-this-question-is-on-topic). But seriously, if it's about Ubuntu and it's not a bug report or a feature request, it's *probably* on-topic here.

Comment: Statistics is a problem with most free-to-distribute projects. Since you don't have any selling numbers you often have no numbers at all.

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu does not count how many users downloads it. Since Ubuntu does not require registrations and because there are so many non-official mirrors, there is simply no way to count how many times it is downloaded (let alone installed).

According to some assumptions there are ~20 million Ubuntu users worldwide. Mark Shuttleworth, the founder of Ubuntu, [announced that Canonical's goal is to get 200 million Ubuntu users by 2015](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/mark-shuttleworth-delivers-uds-keynote-address-sets-goal-for-200-million-ubuntu-users-in-4-years).